# How do I properly format quarto render to match markdown render syntax?

Tags: r, bookdown, quarto

I've been using a purr loop in R (based on this blog: https://damien-datasci-blog.netlify.app/post/2022-01-06-generating-multiple-pdf-at-once-a-use-case-of-rmarkdown-render-in-a-purrr-loop/):

```
    purrr::walk(.x = DataSet$Column, 
     ~ rmarkdown::render(
     input = "MarkdownTemplate.rmd", 
     output_file = glue::glue("Title{.x}.Rmd"), 
     params = list(Column = {.x})))
```

It generates a set of multiple markdown documents at once based on a markdown template where the data for each is filled according to a subset of the dataset (1 of the columns), which is set as a parameter. I'm trying to adapt this to quarto but can't work out the syntax for quarto_render.

I have tried using the quarto_render function but reusing the syntax I used in r markdown does not work even when using a qmd file as the input and output. The quarto website just says that the input needs to be specified but gives no other detail.

Does anyone have any advice on this? Thanks!

````
``` 
library(tidyverse) 
library(tinytex) 
library(bookdown) 
library(openxlsx) 
library(knitr) 
library(quarto) 
scalelist = read.xlsx("AbridgedScaleSummary.xlsx") 
purrr::walk( .x = scalelist$abbreviation, 
             ~ quarto_render( input = "QuartoProjTemplate.qmd", 
                              output_file = glue::glue("Scale-- {.x}.qmd"),
                              execute_params = list(abbreviation = {.x})))
```
````

Comment: What code have you tried with `quarto_render()`? And what errors did you get? I typically use Quarto from the terminal rather than the R console, but the R package seems to be just an interface to the command line tool, see here: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-r Do you have the command line tool installed?

Comment: Also, I see that `quarto_render()` doesn't have the `params` parameter, but rather the `execute_params` parameter. If you used the same syntax, this could also be a reason why it wouldn't work. See here for the docs: https://quarto-dev.github.io/quarto-r/reference/quarto_render.html

Comment: @knitz3 yes I do have the CLI installed. I tried the following (including the change you suggested regarding the parameter):

```
     library(tidyverse)
     library(tinytex)
     library(bookdown)
     library(openxlsx)
     library(knitr)
     library(quarto)

     scalelist =
     read.xlsx("AbridgedScaleSummary.xlsx")

     purrr::walk( .x = scalelist$abbreviation,      ~ quarto_render(
     input = "QuartoProjTemplate.qmd",
     output_file = glue::glue("Scale--     {.x}.qmd"),
     execute_params = list(abbreviation =      {.x})))
```

Comment: and this is the output:

Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error:
! System command 'quarto' failed
---
Backtrace:
  1. purrr::walk(...)
  2. purrr::map(.x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
  3. purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
  6. global .f(.x[[i]], ...)
  7. quarto::quarto_render(...)
  8. processx::run(quarto_bin, args, echo = TRUE)
  9. throw(...)
 10. base::signalCondition(cond)

Comment: try it with `list(abbreviation = .x)`